# How do I export test cases from HP Sprinter as XML import to HP UFT?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, quality-center, hp-quality-center

I have created a Test in **HP Sprinter** and want that test to execute in **HP** **UFT.** . I have gone through [this link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Connecting-Sprinter-to-UFT-to-import-manual-tests/td-p/6077943#.VLz-59KUcQe) but I am unable to export the test cases in .xml format. According to the link this is the only way tests created in HP Sprinter can be used in HP UFT.

These are the steps that I followed from UFT
Click on File- > Add -> GUI test from Sprinter automated Test file
Where i input my .xml file, this is where it throws me an error message saying Failed to import sprinter automated test data file [image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav - if the contents of the link are essential to your question (and I think they are, as they're the steps you've tried so far), could you summarise them in your question instead of just giving the link? Otherwise, as soon as that link decays, this question becomes useless to users of SQA.

Comment: @testerab Hi, as mentioned i have made necessary changes to the question and have edited it.

Comment: @Bruce McLeod: I have made necessary changes to my question. Could you please remove the hold on it.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I'm not familiar with either Sprinter or UFT, so you may get asked for further information by others, but the edits you've made make it clear what you've tried so far.

Comment: Is there anyway I could get my problem solved, because I have posted the same in HP Forums but to no avail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would likely be better answered by contacting vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer can be found here:

http://eyeontesting.com/questions/7855/how-do-i-import-the-hp-sprinter-xml-file-into-hp-u.html

Comment: welcome to sqa.  Can you please expand your answer beyond just a link?  If you have questions about what good answers look like please look at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.  The link is fine but it is useful to have the relevante points quoted in the answer so if the link goes offline it the information is still present.